# How do i set slider value without 'update' firering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I want to be able to set the slider value without getting the update event to fire. I tried with setting a second parameter (fireSetEvent) in the `set` function, but that doesn't work.

```js
nouiContrast = document.getElementById('nouiContrast');
noUiSlider.create(nouiContrast, {
  start: 0,
  step: 0.01,
  behaviour: 'tap',
  connect: [true, false],
  range: {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 1
  }
});
nouiContrast.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  applyFilterValue(6, 'contrast', values[handle]);
});

//....

nouiContrast.noUiSlider.set(val, false);
```

Comment: Can't you set the `start` param with `val`?

Comment: @Mosh Feu, i'm not sure what you mean? I dont want to set the start value. I can set the slider current value with .set() , but i just don't want it to fire the 'update' event. That should only fire when manually changing the slider position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to handle updates only when the user dragging the slider but not when the code set an update, you can listen to the [`slide`](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/#section-slide) event.

From the docs:

> This event is useful when you specifically want to listen to a handle being dragged, but want to **ignore other updates** to the slider value. This event also fires on a change by a 'tap'. In most cases, the `update` is the better choice.

```js
nouiContrast = document.getElementById('nouiContrast');
noUiSlider.create(nouiContrast, {
  start: 0,
  step: 0.01,
  behaviour: 'tap',
  connect: [true, false],
  range: {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 1
  }
});
nouiContrast.noUiSlider.on('slide', function(values, handle) {
  applyFilterValue(6, 'contrast', values[handle]);
});

//....

nouiContrast.noUiSlider.set(val, false);
```